# Atom package manager not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, electron, atom-editor

When ever atom try to connect with the network it shows a error log.
I've tried many ways, removed every atom component again installed but still giving me same error.

> Fetching featured packages failed.Hide output… module.js:600
>   return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
>                    ^
>
> Error: The module
>   '/usr/lib/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/git-utils/build/Release/git.node'
>   was compiled against a different Node.js version using
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the
>   module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:600:18)
>       at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/git-utils/lib/git.js:8:16)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/git-utils/lib/git.js:371:4)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)

Answer (score 1):

Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using npm rebuild ornpm install)

- I suggest that you try re-installing node.js full features via Chocolatey(on Windows) or aptget(Linux)